# Adding a new VS2015 project to source control

Tags: visual-studio-2015, source-control-bindings

I have a VS2015 solution with 2 projects; one is correctly source-controlled in GitHub; the second project (which I added later by moving files from elsewhere) isn't in source control and I can't find how to add it. I have found answers for this for [VS2013 and earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234443/adding-a-new-project-to-an-existing-solution-in-tfs) but the menu items mentioned aren't available in VS2015 (in both my copies anyway - there is no 'SourceControl' item in the File menu.)

Comment: Regular git repository, or are you talking about some extension that integrates GitHub into VS?

Comment: It's an [official extension] (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2015/04/30/announcing-the-github-extension-for-visual-studio/) of VS2015. But if there's a way of achieving this directly on GitHub that would be good, although I'm not experienced with GitHub command line.

Answer (score 0):

With regular git repositories all you should have to do is right click the solution and then choose Commit. It should offer you to add those files unless they're matched by a rule in .gitignore

Whether or not it gets automatically pushed to GitHub or whether you have to do other things to do that I don't know, not using the Extension.

Comment: That's the problem, there's no option to 'commit' in the right-click menu. Perhaps I should have mentioned that, sorry. When I make changes to files in the other project, the commit option is there. But for this project it's not.